# Google Cloud - Monitor running on Microsoft Display Driver instead of NVIDIA K80 GPU

Tags: virtualization, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016, graphics-processing-unit, nvidia

My Google Cloud Instance is running on Microsoft Display Driver,instead of the GPU.I tried to install Hyper-V,but Google Cloud Processors don't support it.Please help,i need to run Unity,but can't without the GPU.I'm running 6-core Intel Xeon CPU(i tried with 8 core also),16GB RAM and NVIDIA K80 on Windows Server 2016.Please help me i need to initialize the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

"Hyper-V" as well as ESX, and Xen are not currently supported in GCP and here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

However, to use nested virtualization, you can start a VM instance as normal on Compute Engine and then install a KVM-compatible hypervisor on the VM instance so you can run another VM instance on top of that hypervisor.

You can learn more about GPU and its usages at Google Compute Engine at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/).